# Error while starting the Standalone Agent Using Node Manager : "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I'm trying to start the Standalone Agent Using Node Manager with this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/tutorial-creating-standalone-agent/#StartingtheStandaloneAgentUsingNodeManager

(Windows)

Node manager has been started with command:

```
startNodeManager.cmd
```

But can't start the agent OracleDIAgent1 with command:

```
startComponent.cmd OracleDIAgent1
```

Full output:

```
Please enter Node Manager password:
Connecting to Node Manager ...
<Jan 15, 2019 4:54:57 PM MSK> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling the CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true.>
<Jan 15, 2019 4:54:57 PM MSK> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG128 to HMACDRBG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true.>
<Jan 15, 2019 4:54:58 PM MSK> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090909> <Using the configured custom SSL Hostname Verifier implementation: weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier$NullHostnameVerifier.>
This Exception occurred at Tue Jan 15 16:54:58 MSK 2019.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
Error: Error occurred while performing nmConnect : Cannot connect to Node Manager. : Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :

Exiting WebLogic Scripting Tool.

Done
```

File nodemanager.properties has SecureListener off:

```
SecureListener=false
```

Please help to start agent. Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Stop your node manager then try to change the value as "SecureListener=false" and in the console, verify the node manager protocol is "plain". Restart your node manager.